# Unable configure in BizTalk logic app adapter

Tags: biztalk, azure-logic-apps

I Installed BizTalk logic app adapter,  I followed Microsoft document to configure logic app, [Install and use the Logic App Adapter on BizTalk Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/logic-app-adapter)

I created an application in IIS for management and service. Issue is when I browse management service I am getting 503 error.

I tried the URL with "/schemas?"  still getting 503 error. I didn't see any schemas in management folder under logic apps folder.

[image]

Did miss any thing here.

[image]